# Android HttpURLConnection send parameters

Tags: php, android, parameters, httpurlconnection

I used to use HttpClient but now is deprecated, so now I would like to use HttpURLConnection, but I cant find out how to properly use it.

I want to send two strings via post to a php script: ("username", "password"). How can I achieve this?

Comment: @Sanaoop No it uses NameValuePair and it is deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `NameValuePair` is deprecated. Try this

```
public String  performPostCall(String requestURL,
            HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {

        URL url;
        String response = "";
        try {
            url = new URL(requestURL);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);


            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                String line;
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                    response+=line;
                }
            }
            else {
                response="";

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }
```

....

```
  private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
```

**EDIT**

If you don't need the `ArrayList<NameValuePair>` for parameters, this is a shorter solution that builds the query string using the `Uri.Builder` class:

```
URL url = new URL("http://yoururl.com");
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);

Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
        .appendQueryParameter("firstParam", paramValue1)
        .appendQueryParameter("secondParam", paramValue2)
        .appendQueryParameter("thirdParam", paramValue3);
String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(query);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
os.close();

conn.connect();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's that I've looking all day on the internet, and I don't get it. How do I send the strings (password and username)

Comment: @GustavoSerna Hope it helped.. :) :) Happie coding broah